# How Do I Remove Ubuntu and Install Windows 7?

Tags: uninstall

I have purchased a new Dell Insperion 620S desktop. It has Ubuntu installed by default.

I want to remove Ubuntu, and install Windows 7 instead.

Please help me understand the steps to remove Ubuntu.

Comment: Put in your windows cd and format the disk when installing

Comment: Note that to install Windows 7, you will need a Windows 7 CD and License Key.

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu question but a Windows question. Why not ask on a windows forum?

Comment: I didn't put my answer as an answer because I honestly thought this was a troll... Priyank ... prank .. maybe that was just me

Answer (score 6):

Format the hard drive NTFS.
Install Win 7.

Answer (score 3):

It is not Ubuntu's responsibility to be able to uninstall itself or to be able to install Windows for you :)

Windows installer, as far as I am aware, is perfectly capable of re-partitioning the hard drive and installing Windows. As @Thomas Ward pointed out, all you need to do is to put Windows 7 CD into your optical disk drive and reboot your computer. If you do not have a Windows 7 CD or a CD/DVD drive - you need to obtain one. Any problems with installing Windows are outside of the scope of this site, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Start your laptop & go to bios setup > boot section & make your laptop to boot from cd (if not booting from cd ) { to go to bios setup when laptop start you will see to go bios press Esc or f1 or some key you will see }

insert windows 7 cd & install windows 7 ...

---

if u dont want to use Ubuntu as host operating system , u can also install Ubuntu in virtual machine ( virtual box is the software )

In Ubuntu software's are free & you will love when you use it & one of the biggest benefit is that guys here will help you if you need anything 24/7 support .

Answer (score -1):

Load up a [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) live CD and format the hard drive.

Comment: This could have more info, and is not the easiest solution.