# Problems in dual-boot of ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8.1

Tags: boot, windows-8

100% Newbie here. Sorry for all the dumbness.

So, I have an HP Pavilion Laptop 15 series. It have windows 8.1 pre-installed OS.I dual boot it with ubuntu 14.04. It was working fine. But then, I realised that i don't need windows no more. So, I deleted windows completely(and the recovery partition also) and installed ubuntu 14.04. I think it was my biggest mistake. As you know that I have dual booted before, so I have configurated BIOS settings like disabling secure boot and enabling boot from dvd. A blue screen from where I have booted ubuntu in my laptop(I was thinking that it belongs to my laptop. but, its not because after removing windows, that screen was also gone. I think that was made for recovery). But now many functions are not working correctly like wire-less card is not working. So now, I want to dual boot windows 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04. I know the fact that to dual boot, I need to install windows first and then I have to make partition for ubuntu and then ubuntu will be installed. I have an original iso image of windows 8.1 with key.I don't have recovery disc. I have made its bootable usb and dvd. But, when I try to install windows, It doesn't boot neither dvd nor usb. I can't install windows 8.1. What should i do now?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why disable Fast Boot on Windows 8 when having dual booting?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting)

Comment: @DnrDevil Doesn't look like a duplicate to me.

Comment: after reinstalling ubuntu, everything is working fine now.  But, how can i install windows again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Remove Ubuntu and Install Windows 7?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102074/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-and-install-windows-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To boot from other devices than the main drive you need to go into your BIOS settings or call a menu at the computer start up and choose what device to boot from. If you know this and did this, then there must be something wrong with your DVD and USB stick.
2. You may want to search for and check how to install Windows *after* Ubuntu. This will save you some time and work. You can resize the current partitions and make new ones from a live Ubuntu session.

Comment: Write more about what doesn't work. That's in Ubuntu, I gather? Another thing, have you tried to install Windows from another source like an original DVD?

Comment: I don't have original dvd. Actually the iso image of windows i have, it is downloaded from dreamspark.

Comment: But what do you mean by 'not working'? Is anything at all going on? What then? Or is it completely nothing? Have you checked your BIOS settings then? Can you play a movie on your DVD? Can you use your USB for other purposes than booting?

Comment: Speakers are not working, and i can't change brightness level. when it was dual booted, prt sc button was taking screenshots. But now, it is also not working.

Comment: I tried ubuntu dvd. It is booting at startup. Should I reinstall ubuntu?

Comment: It seems like a good idea, judging by what you post. I'd format the disk completely and install Ubuntu. Then I'd do all the possible upgrades and see how it works. Your laptop is a popular one, everything should be fine.

Comment: I'd also take into considaration restoring BIOS settings to defaults.

Comment: Everything is working fine now. But what about windows part?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Installing_Windows_After_Ubuntu If your Windows doesn't boot, it's most likely broken. I think you can download an image from Microsoft's website. Better avaid other sources, as you can get very bad viruses, which will spoil your laptop pretty badly.

Comment: Provided you have an original Windows key, you can always call them and ask for assistance.